# How to add a DependencyProperty to a WInForms UserControl for binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dependency-properties, axwindowsmediaplayer

I followed [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/using-windows-media-player-com-in-wpf/) to import the WinForms windows media player into WPF.

I now want to bind the URL property of the control in my WPF app. However, when I try to do so I get an error because the control does not inherit from the DependencyObject class.

I tried to register the URL as a DependencyProperty like so:

```
partial class WMPControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(WMPControl));
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // axWindowsMediaPlayer1
        // 
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Enabled = true;
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Name = "axWindowsMediaPlayer1";
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OcxState")));
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(634, 437);
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // UserControl1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
        this.Name = "UserControl1";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(634, 437);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("URL", typeof(string), typeof(AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer));


    private AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWindowsMediaPlayer1;
}
```

But from the WPF I am getting: A 'Binding' can not be set on the 'URL' property of type 'AxWindowsMediaPlayer'. A 'Binding' can only be set on the DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: It means that WMPControl should inherit from DependencyObject for that to work.
Also:
https://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html
look under:
How to create a DependencyProperty

Comment: Without more context, including a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates your scenario, it's impossible to say for sure what the best answer in your case would be. However, it seems likely to me you would be better off writing a WPF `UserControl`, which is already a `DependencyObject` (the requirement you need to meet in order to implement dependency property), in which you host the WPM ActiveX control _directly_ in the `WindowsFormsHost` object, instead of adding the extra layer of Winforms `UserControl`. Alternatively, consider using `MediaElement` instead.